# Disabling Browser Caching for a Web Page, Not Working for IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, caching, browser

I wanted to disable the **Browser Cache** for a page. After referring some article about Browser cache disabling concept I found a solution to achieve it.

Here is the code I using:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

I included this command between HEAD tag.

But this is not working in IE. Could someone help to rectify it. How can I make it work, any ideas will be helpful.

Thank you...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind could you please suggest me How can we do this with JavaScript. @Moogs